# Getting the output of console application by redirection standard output | C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application which prints something and waits for input.
I am trying to launch that application get the output and then send something back. However, it seems that I am unable to get the initial output. Instead the program blocks when I try to read the redirected output.

Code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
//p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

p.Start();

//StreamWriter inputWriter = p.StandardInput;
//StreamReader outputReader = p.StandardOutput;
Console.WriteLine("Step 1");
string s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine("Step 2");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Step 2 is never printed. What am I missing?

Comment: You use ReadToEnd(), so it will block until everything is read (that is - until child process terminates).

Comment: I have tried several version of Read, what you suggest? Please note that I'm using C# for the first time for this specific task.

Comment: Are you sure the process that you started terminated?  For example if you were execution cmd.exe it can't ReadToEnd until stdout is closed.

Comment: This is quite normal, the original programmer forgot to flush stdout before asking for input.  Traditional bug, he just never wrote it with I/O redirection in mind, he assumed it would always be used interactively.  Nothing you can do about it, other than using a telephone to ask for a fix.